# Create Indicator Color/Light With A Single Column in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to create indicator from one column called "FIELD". Basically, the column has two string values "EOD" and "SOD". The indicator that i need to create is:

If SOD > EOD then red color

IF EOD < SOD then green color

IF SOD = EOD then yellow color

Could anyone please help with this.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This just works for a table visual in Power BI.
Click on your table visual and select a column by the values:

[image]

Right click on your column and `Conditional formatting > Background Color`:

[image]

Now enter the conditions in the upcoming dialog and you are done.